# C++ array program

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm very confused when it comes to arrays and I've got a mini-project on using them but i'm stuck at a certain part in my program and I don't know what to do next, can anyone help?

the question is:

> "Write a C++ program that reads 5 integers from the screen (provided by the user) and determines the largest integer. You MUST use an array to store the 5 integers.
>
> ```
> The following shows a sample output of the program.
>
> Enter 5 integers: 15 36 -8 92 56
> The largest integer is 92 "
> ```

what i've got so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int userIntegers[5];

cout<<"Enter 5 integers: ";
cin>>userIntegers[0];




//system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: read up on `for` loops. Especially `for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)`

Comment: You were able to read into `userIntegers[0]` but what happened to the rest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the thing you have to do. You need to use a **FOR** or **WHILE** loop to get the certain number of user input and store them in array.

```
int userIntegers[5];
int largest = 0;

cout<<"Enter 5 integers: ";
for (int i=0; i<5; i++) //Use for loop upto how many numbers you need to get as input.
{
    cin>>userIntegers[i];//get the input from user and store it in array at the index
    /*If the input is the larger than prev largest or For special case to handle if all the values entered is less than zero.*/
    if(largest < userIntegers[i] || largest == 0) 
    {
        largest = userIntegers[i];//Assign the largest number to the variable.
    }
}
 cout<<"Largest Integer is: "<<largest;
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can do more easily (using isstringstrem and INT_MIN):

```
int maxnumber = INT_MIN; // for being sure to have at lest one number above 
int number;
string s;

cout<<"Enter 5 integers: ";
cin >> s;

std::istringstream steam( s );
while(steam >> number) {
 if (number > maxnumber) {
  maxnumber = number;
 }
}
```

EDIT:
If you need an array @Sridhar seem have your answer (but think about using INT_MIN http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/)